# What's the difference between GPUs Familys be it NVIDIA or ATI?

Tags: gpu

Just started doing research on the hardwre/GPU world but still, there are some things i dont understand/know. For exmample, what's the difference between the GeForce, Quadro, Tesla & Tegra for NVIDIA and the ATIFirepro, ATIRadeon & ATI Mobility Radeon for ATI?. Im not asking for NVIDIA Vs ATI thread, just the main diferences between the GPU families.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a nutshell:

**GeForce** cards are NVidia's mainstream GPUs.

**Quadro** cards are designed for workstations rather than mainstream use and gaming. They're used for faster digital content creation and CAD (computer aided design) applications where more power is required from the GPU rather than the CPU for image processing.

**Tesla** are based on Quadro cards if I remember correctly, and are intended for high performance computing rather than mainstream use and gaming, just like the Quadro.

**Tegra** is not a video card by itself but rather an entire small computing platform for mobile devices. They're comprised of a CPU, memory, GPU, and storage space.

---

**ATI Firepro** cards is ATI's version of the Quadro, a card for high performance computing on workstations.

**Radeon** cards are ATI's mainstream consumer cards, like the GeForce series.

**Mobility Radeon** cards are Radeon GPUs for mobile devices, usually found in laptops.

Comment: I didn't know about telsa and tegra till now,thanks John :)

Comment: No problem! I hope my information is fairly accurate. There is a lot more interesting things on the Nvidia site as well: http://www.nvidia.com

Comment: Sounds right, but i think its *tesla* not *telsa*

Comment: Sounds right indeed